# What's difference between boost/thread.hpp and boost/thread/thread.hpp?

Tags: multithreading, boost

I found that both boost/thread.hpp and boost/thread/thread.hpp can solve the error that says:

```
 /home/ira/code/pcl_standalone/test1/t.cpp:33:16: error: ‘boost::this_thread’ has not been declared
```

What's difference between them?

Which should I use?

Thank you~

Comment: try opening the former file. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boost consists of several separate sub-projects. Each provides a header file in the form of boost/.hpp to include most or all needed header files to use all features of that sub-project.

So boost/thread.hpp includes you all of the thread sub-project, while boost/thread/thread.hpp includes just the special thread implementation of the thread sub-project.